# What does it mean when it says that it "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects" on python

Tags: python

I have been working on a pythagorus theorem calculator on python
Here is my code so far:

```
a = int(raw_input("what is length a?"))
b = int(raw_input("what is length b?"))
a2 = a*a 
b2 = b*b 
c2 = a2+b2
c = c2**0.5
print "the length of c is " + c
```

It will not work on the last line. It throws the following error:

```
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Exactly what the error says - it can't put a string ("the length of c is") and a float (`c`) together. You need to tell it to treat the number as a string by casting it.

Comment: Try google next time. I got about 50 results when i googled "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects"

Answer (score 1):

Just what it says: `c` is a float, but `"the length of c is "` is a string. As a quick fix you can do this: `"the length of c is " + str(c)`, but you will want to learn about [string formatting.](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html)

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this and it works well. If "the length of c is " is the string, why is it not str("the length of c is ") + c?

Comment: because `"the length of c is "` is already a string, it does not need to be cast to a string type with `str()`, it is not the problem. The problem is the `c` variable; it is not of the type `string`, and therefore does not have the class attributes that are inherent to strings (like concatenation in this case). In your scope, `c` is of type `int`, so we must cast it to a string before we can treat it as such. Think of it this way, `c` being an integer can not be concatenated in the same way as you cant set its value to upper case, who ever heard of upper case '45'?

Answer (score 0):

`c` is an `int`, `"the length of c is "` is a string

You would have to say

```
print "the length of c is ", str(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `print "the length of c is %.3f" % (c,)`

Concatenation is combining strings together, and Python doesn't automatically convert non-strings to strings (unlike Java).